# Распаковка архивов

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.

Требуется распаковать как можно большее разнообразие архивов на PHP. На данный момент реализовал Zip и Rar. Остаются tar, tar.gz, tar.bz2. Может кто помочь с ними? Вроде как через PharData можно распаковать. Только вот что-то не нашел как. Ну и может еще какие популярные архивы я упустил?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По ссылке [PHP Class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/945-PHP-Create-tar-gzip-bzip2-zip-extract-tar-gzip-bzip2-.html) для упаковки/распаковки tar, gzip и bzip2.

В файле [readme](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/6584.html) описание на англ.; в файле [examples](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/10489.html) – примеры кода с комментариями на англ.

Comment: @sergiks, Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы.

Comment: @Expert ♦♦  постарался.